# Root certifcate from an CA company which can be encrpyted by SoftHSM

Tags: java, security, encryption, ca, hsm

3 questions:

1.Does anybody know a CA company which allows me to put the bought CA certficate inside SoftHSM (the same as an HSM but without any hardware, this is pure software)?

2.Is it hard to work with the PKCS11 interface? I have a Java application which will sign documents. But I need to communicate through the PKCS11 interface. Anybody had any experience with it before? Is there any tutorial on this?

3.If I buy an trusted certficate, why don't they deliver it in .crt? I have a trial certificate, but my browser just imports it. Don't see where to download this certificate so I can store it my hsm.

Please help to clear my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, this did not get on my radar before:

1. Any company should do this. *You* generate a key pair and create a certificate request. Then they sign your request and give you a certificate. Where *you* store the private key is normally not their concern. For higher end certificates your identity is though.
2. If you just need to sign and you have an RSA or ECDSA private key then you can use the Java PKCS#11 provider. You then simply use the standard `Signature` class after configuration. To configure the HSM right is an art in it's own though.
3. You can normally export your certificate again, otherwise right click and download. The way it is handled is because of the MIME type. You could also use e.g. wget, which would just download using the link you provide.

Comment: Very late answer, so I sincerely hope you already "cleared your mind" :)

Comment: correction to 1: 

I already figured it out, Companies who can deliver a CA root certificate (which adobe reader automatically trusts) won't allow it to give the certificate without a security layer upon it. There are 2 options: receive your pcks12 in an USB-Token or buy a Hardware-hsm (very expensive).

Comment: That should not be applicable if you generate your (TLS) key pair yourself, only if they have to send a private key together with the certificate. Getting a private key / certificate by mail could be required for systems that are not linked to DNS though (i.e. anybody could request a certificate under any name). I *presume* you mean receive a *server* certificate that is *trusted* by a known root certificate by the way.